# WIn API Basic Paint program

Tags: winapi, mousemove

Just trying to learn a bit of Win API. Im trying to make a basic drawing app, a bit like MS Paint.

For the time being im trying to get one function to work which is, when you left click and drag the mouse around the screen a line is drawn behind the mouse. Heres what i have so far, but for some reason:

1) the line starts drawing straight away rather then waiting for the left click 
2) the line isn't solid its very dotty.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{


    if(MK_LBUTTON){
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,5,RGB(0, 0, 255));
    SelectObject(hdc, hPen);

    int x = LOWORD(lParam);
    int y = HIWORD(lParam);

    MoveToEx(hdc,x,y,NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
    }
    else
        break;

}
```

}

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

On `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` you have to set a variable in your program to `true` ("yes mouse is currently down), in your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` you then check that variable and only draw it it is `true`. On `WM_LBUTTONUP` you then set that variable to `false`. (The variable should be initialized to false).

Comment: Sorry im not following what your saying, could you please explain a bit more? Thankyou for your reply

Comment: Sure. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` triggers when-ever the mouse is moved, not only when moved and a button is down. So to draw only when the button is down you first have to make your program "remember" whether it is down.

Comment: so use WM_LBUTTONDOWN with a bool or something and when that equals true then trigger the WM_MOUSEMOVE?

Comment: not exactly. Like this: declare `bool isDown` outside of the function. And use: `case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: isDown=true; break; case WM_LBUTTONUP: isDown=false; break; case WM_MOUSEMOVE: if(isDown) draw(); break;`

Comment: Ive tried shuffling things about and implementing what you said, but no luck, i just get a blank screen and the loading icon

Comment: But didn't it draw before? Try from your last version that drew something and just add the boolean.